# Remove CSS property from class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a CSS class named `.co_dcrTable_Header` with the following CSS:

```
.co_dcrTable_Header {
    color: #212121;
    display: block;
    max-height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px 0; 
}
```

Is there a way to remove the `overflow` property with jQuery?

Comment: `$(".co_dcrTable_Header").css("overflow","whateverYouWantItToBe");` (leave blank to erase the property) should work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove CSS Attribute with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398870/remove-css-attribute-with-jquery)

Comment: Do you want to remove the property from the _class_, or from the _elements selected by_ the class?

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the elements with the class assigned, and set the overflow value to something other than hidden. Blank will remove it completely I think.

```
$('.co_dcrTable_Header').css('overflow', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.co_dcrTable_Header').css('overflow', 'visible');
```

You can set the property to be empty or any of the below:

> visible, hidden, scroll, auto, initial, inherit

Bear in mind that `visible` is the default property.

Comment: This is not removing, This is overwriting. And is not a n answer to this question.