# Clear all changes done with jquery animation before starting a new animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I used jQuery animation to animate some div's. I there any way to clear all changes done to first div before animation second div?

```
      $(".order-b").click(function(event){
        $(".order-t").animate({top:'30%'}, "slow" );
      });

      $(".counsel-b").click(function(){
        $(".counsel-t").animate({top:'30%'}, "slow" );
      });


<div class="process-bars">
   <!-- first DIV -->
   <div class="order-b">
      <div class="order-t">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
          <h1>Order</h1>
      </div>                                      
   </div>

   <!-- Second DIV -->
   <div class="counsel-b">
      <div class="counsel-t">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
          <h1>Order</h1>
      </div>                                        
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.order-t, counsel-t {
position:absolute;
top:52%;
width: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
z-index:2;
```

}

I want to clear animation of the first div when I click on the second div.
How can I do that?! I don't want to do it like the code below:

```
     $(".order-b").click(function(event){
        $(".order-t").animate({top:'30%'}, "slow" );
        $(".counsel-t").animate({top:'52%'}, "slow" );
      });
```

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle or something? It would help to have your css and where is `.counsel-t` in your html?

Comment: I edited the code. there was a mistake

Comment: Can you add your CSS? And why do you have click functions in the first block of code and then different click functions in this second block?

Comment: what do you mean clear the changes done? Do you mean move it back to `top:0%` before running the second animation?

Comment: @Afshin are you saying you want the first div to animate, and then when its done, animate the second one?

Comment: @jmore009 when I animate the first div, it's moved to top:30% position. Then, when I click on the second div, first of all I want the first div to get back to the top:52% position, and then move the content of second div to top:30% position.

Comment: @Afshin I get it, posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

Like shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9398960/1585362, to clear the css that has been added to an element via jquery you can use this: 
`$('.element').removeAttr('style');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function with `.animate()` which will run the second animation after the first one has completed:

```
$(".counsel-b").click(function(){
  $(".order-t").animate({top:'52%'}, "slow", function(){
      $(".counsel-t").animate({top:'30%'}, "slow" );
  });          
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d2uvapkr/)

Comment: You know what?! there are more that one animation for each div which I did not mentioned in this question. So, if I want to do this for all of them, there will be a real junk. I was searching for a short code to do this.

Comment: If you need help with a specific problem you need to post the exact issue. This is how you do it, and as short as it's going to get