# Can't remove css property with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I add css property to a button with: `$('#salvaImpegno').css("cursor", "not-allowed");` and it works.

But I can't remove it. I tried with: `$('#salvaImpegno').removeProp("cursor");`, but it doesn't work.

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove CSS "top" and "left" attributes with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398870/remove-css-top-and-left-attributes-with-jquery)

Comment: `.removeprop()` undoes `.prop()`. it has nothing to do with css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `css` is not a property.

Use

```
$('#salvaImpegno').css('cursor', '');
```

or

```
$('#salvaImpegno').css('cursor', 'default');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because css is not a property.

You have to remove the property `style`.

like this:

```
$('#salvaImpegno').removeProp("style");
```

or more correctly

```
 $('#salvaImpegno').removeAttr("style");
```

because style is an attribute, more than a property of an element.

But it will remove all the styles you added through .css() method. If you want to only reset cursor property refer other answers.

Answer (score 0):

instead you can try using .addClass(), so maybe you can do something like

```
$('#salvaImpegno').css("cursor", "not-allowed");
```

and then when you want to remove the "cursor" you can add a class that overrides the other like this.

```
/----CSS---/

.cursorOverride{
  cursor: pointer !important;
}

/---js---jQuery----/

$('#salvaImpegno').addClass("cursorOverride");
```

If you want to be able to reomve the class you can do that with .removeClass(). I hope this helps!